# Snippet Designer that allows for keyword replacement Visual Studio 2010 SQL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql, code-snippets

I am currently trying to use [Snippet Designer](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/) to speed up my development. I am either missing how to best leverage it or missing a feature that I need. I am looking for assistance accomplishing the following through a snippet.

I create many Tables that follow a pattern and want to somewhat automate it.

*Example SP*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectTable]
(
    ObjectID [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    ObjectName [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL
)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is replace `Object` with the name of the table.

*Example*

[image: Create Table Dialog]

[image: Using snippet]

[image: After Snippet Replacement]

So I would like to pull the tables name, or even if I can just select `Person` text and then insert the snippet and use the selected text. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Snippet Designer, but in the SSMS 2012 snippet feature you can reuse a literal in the text of the command.  I don't know about picking up the value you had selected, but you can easily replace the value in multiple places.  If you copy the Create Table snippet and modify the Snippet block like this:

```
         <Snippet> 
             <Declarations>   
                    <Literal>    
                           <ID>SchemaName</ID>    
                           <ToolTip>Name of the schema</ToolTip>    
                           <Default>dbo</Default>    
                    </Literal>    
                    <Literal>    
                           <ID>Tablename</ID>    
                           <ToolTip>Root Name of Table</ToolTip>    
                           <Default>MyTableNameRoot</Default>    
                    </Literal>    
             </Declarations>    
             <CodeLanguage="SQL">    
                    <![CDATA[CREATE TABLE [$SchemaName$].[$Tablename$Table]    
(    
       $Tablename$ID [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL,    
       $Tablename$Name [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL    
);$end$]]>    
             </Code>    
       </Snippet>
```

Then you should be able to replace the "MyTableNameRoot" once and have it replaced in the two column names as well.